# Kubernetes Network policies traffic between namespaces from one to one pods only

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have several namespaces in a cluster and I need to do the following:

1. traffic from namespace 1 to namespace 2 goes only to one pod
2. traffic from namespace 2 to namespace 1 goes only to one pod.
3. traffic from and to the other namespaces would go unimpeded.

There is an idea to hang a certain label on all pods of namespace 1, except for the necessary pod and on all pods of namespace 2 to hang another label, except for the necessary pod and prohibit traffic between namespaces by labels.

How can this be implemented using kubernetes network policies?

Answer (score -1):

i think you can Achieve
1.Create a NetworkPolicy in namespace 1 that allows ingress traffic only from the specific pod in namespace 2, and denies all other ingress traffic
2.Create a NetworkPolicy in namespace 2 that allows ingress traffic only from the specific pod in namespace 1, and denies all other ingress traffic
3.For all other namespaces, create a NetworkPolicy that allows all ingress and egress traffic
tell me if you need yaml samples

Comment: Recommend adding the yaml samples or pointing to supporting information that indicates how to do the task.  In it's present form, the answer only (slightly) confirms that the original poster can do what they want.  Providing the extra information will allow them to progress and lend credibility to your answer.  Additionally, Stack overflow and related sites have lots of easy formatting options that can make reading your questions and answers much easier.